# Using std::function as a template argument + non-template function overloading

Tags: templates, c++11, overloading

Here is the problem. The code at the bottom of the forum topic is just the most simple example of what I think is a compiler error reproduced in case of overloaded function deduction based just on argument types.
There is a function:

```
void f(const T& v, const std::function< bool( const T& ) >& validator );
```

... that takes some value and a validator. So, since there is no need to validate a bool there is a validator-less overloaded version of the function:

```
void f(const bool& v);
```

To be most precise, the generation of a function, taking bool as a value, by the function template should be disabled:

```
template<bool>
void f(const bool& v, const std::function< bool(const bool&) >& validator) = delete;
```

... but that is not made for the sake of code simplicity.

If one compiles the code using MSVC12, included in MSVS2013, the code at the bottom of the topic would not compile. Both lines:

```
f(5, [](const int& a){ return a != 0; });
f(5, & isIntValid );
```

... will issue a C2660 error telling that "f" does not take 2 arguments or there is no such overloaded version that takes that as much arguments. This, of course, is a total lie and a compiler bug.
Now, comment the line:

```
#define USE_FUNCTOR
```

... so that to enable the version of "f" with function pointer argument as a validator instead of a functor. Then the code compiles perfectly well. If you like replace the function pointer argument with a plain bool one:

```
template< typename T >
void f(const T& v, const bool isValid )
{
    if (isValid)
    {
        std::cout << v;
    }
}
```

... and then call the function:

```
f( 5, false );
```

There won't be any compiler errors again.
An explicit fix: call the template version of f by explicitly specifying the template argument type:
The lines:

```
f(5, [](const int& a){ return a != 0; });
f(5, & isIntValid );
```

... should become:

```
f<int>(5, [](const int& a){ return a != 0; });
f<int>(5, & isIntValid );
```

But, as obvious such differentiated usage is not uniform accross all "f" overloads.
Note that the bug is not reproduced when using non-template code:

```
void b(const int a, const std::function< bool(const int& v) >& validator)
{
    if (validator(a))
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}

void b(const int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

// ...
b(5, [](const int& a){ return a != 0; });
b(5);
```

The conclusion: using std::function as a parameter in a template function that is overloaded by a non-template one gives unexpected wrong overloaded function deduction results.

The question: how to pass a std::function as a parameter to a template function without sacrificing the convenience of not having to explicitly state the function template argument?

Here is the code reproducing the compiler bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#define USE_FUNCTOR
#ifdef USE_FUNCTOR
template< typename T >
void f(const T& v, const std::function< bool( const T& ) >& validator )
{
    if (validator(v))
    {
        std::cout << v;
    }
}
#else
template< typename T >
void f(const T& v, bool(*validator)(const T& a))
{
    if ((*validator)(v))
    {
        std::cout << v;
    }
}
#endif

void f(const bool& v)
{
    std::cout << (v ? "yes" : "no" );
}

bool isIntValid(const int& a)
{
    return a != 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#ifdef USE_FUNCTOR
    f(5, [](const int& a){ return a != 0; });
#endif
    f(5, & isIntValid );
    f(true);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `T` is in a deduced context in both the parameter `v` and the parameter `validator`, which means the caller would have to provide an actual `std::function` object for the deduction to work. A lambda is *not* of type `std::function`.

Since you want deduction on the first parameter only, a helper to make the second `T` occurrence non-deduced is what you need:

```
template <class T>
struct NonDeduced
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
void f(const T& v, const std::function< bool( const typename NonDeduced<T>::type& ) >& validator );
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd869649d256fbbf)

---

As a side note, the syntax for the "deleted specialisation" you sketched is incorrect. It would be:

```
template<>
void f(const bool& v, const std::function< bool(const bool&) >& validator) = delete;
```

Comment: Make it `template<>` in MSVS2013 and watch the result.
Previously it was `template<>` but not using MSVS2013.

Comment: @Ivan `template<bool>` defines a *new* template, not a specialisation of the one you have. If MSVC has problems with this code, then try explicit argument: `template <> void f<bool>(`

Comment: I should probably read more. So, as a side question from the topic, how (and why) one would actually use `template<bool>` as a template?

Comment: @Ivan Too broad a question, I'm afraid. Simply when you need parameterisation by a compile-time `bool`. Look at `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional` for a `std` example (they're classes, not functions, though).

Answer (score 0):

Although the Microsoft compiler gives a pretty misleading error, it is correct to reject your code.

The two parameter version does not get picked, because your lambda or function pointer can not be used to deduce the template argument of `std::function`.

I would suggest making the function type a template parameter:

```
template< typename T, typename F >
void f(const T& v, F validator )
{
    if (validator(v))
    {
        std::cout << v;
    }
}
```

Clang is more clear about the errors:

```
main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<bool (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at main.cpp:38:10)'
void f(const T& v, const std::function< bool( const T& ) >& validator )

main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<bool (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against 'bool (*)(const int &)'
void f(const T& v, const std::function< bool( const T& ) >& validator )
```

Comment: It was previous version of the code was exactly as yours but the target of the std::function code was to prevent the user from providing wrong validators:

    char* b( const int& v );
So this is a perfectly valid validator. The return value would be implicitly converted to bool. Restricting the possible validator types also results in less generated functions by the compiler.

"The two parameter version does not get picked, because your lambda or function pointer can not be used to deduce the template argument of std::function."

Is it explicitly stated by the standard?